# 'Spring.xml' IOException issues with migrated project from Eclipse to IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, spring, ide, intellij-idea, runtime-error

I have pulled a Java project from TSF which another colleague created using Eclipse, however, whenever I open the project in IntelliJ it get the following runtime exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing  XML document from class path resource
>   [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
>   path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>   ...
>   ...

I have used Maven to download all the project dependencies which seem to have worked fine as I am not getting any compile time exceptions.

I have uploaded most of the project configuration settings to this [**imgur album**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUqs1.jpg), it should hopefully help.

---

**Main.java**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

---

**Spring.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.3.xsd">

        <bean id="ApplicationConfiguration" class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.ApplicationConfiguration" />
        <bean id="TableFactory" class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.TableFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="ApplicationConfiguration" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="ItemFactory" class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.datagen.ItemFactory"/>        
        <bean id="ItemWritersPool" class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.ItemWritersPool">        
            <constructor-arg ref="ItemWriterFactory" />
            <constructor-arg ref="ApplicationConfiguration" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="ItemWriterFactory" class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.ItemWriterFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="ApplicationConfiguration" />
            <constructor-arg ref="TableFactory" />
            <constructor-arg ref="ItemFactory" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="ItemReadersPool" class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.ItemReadersPool">
            <constructor-arg ref="ItemReaderFactory" />
            <constructor-arg ref="ApplicationConfiguration" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="ItemReaderFactory" class="com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.ItemReaderFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="TableFactory" />
        </bean>

</beans>
```

---

**Project.iml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="EclipseModuleManager">
    <conelement value="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER" />
    <src_description expected_position="0">
      <src_folder value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" expected_position="0" />
    </src_description>
  </component>
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="Spring" name="Spring">
      <configuration>
        <fileset id="fileset" name="Spring Application Context" removed="false">
          <file>file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/spring.xml</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/io/netty/netty/3.6.3.Final/netty-3.6.3.Final.jar!/org/jboss/netty/container/spring/beans.xml</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AbstractAsyncConfiguration.class</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/cache/annotation/AbstractCachingConfiguration.class</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/context/annotation/LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.class</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/context/annotation/MBeanExportConfiguration.class</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ProxyAsyncConfiguration.class</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class</file>
          <file>jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfiguration.class</file>
          <file>file://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar</file>
        </fileset>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_7" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    [-- some items manually removed --]
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    [-- some items manually removed --]
      </component>
    </module>
```

---

Any advise and/or suggestion will greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: spring.xml is in src/main/resources?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, no it is not. I tried creating the directory and placing it there but it did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems ok in your config so I checked using a small project and it appears that the problem may come from the redundant namespaces you are using in your XML headers.

Try modifying the following this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.3.xsd">
```

To result in something like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

If that does not work you can also tweak your `.iml` file by doing the following:

`org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true"`. You can test quickly by replacing `true` with `false` and let IntelliJ reload your project.
I don't know why IntelliJ ignore your `spring.xml` file, but if you use 2 separate directories for sources and resources, as Maven suggests, your problem should disappear.

You should also create the directory `src/main/resources` and place your `spring.xml` file there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, Thanks for answer. Not at work at the moment, will try your suggestion tomorrow and hopefully mark this question as answered :)

Comment: while changing `isMavenModule` to `false` did not resolve the problem, your suggestion trigger an idea that ended-up solving the problem I was facing. I have edited your answer to include my solution so I could make it as answered ;) - Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can be a problem with the working dir. This [blog post](http://justsomejavaguy.blogspot.fi/2011/06/filenotfoundexception-when-running-unit.html) explains the problem and how to fix it.

IntelliJ differs from Eclipse in that it sets the working directory to **project** root which may not be the same as the top level directory of the **module** you are working on.

This can be fixed in the run configurations by setting the working directory to `$MODULE_DIR$`.

If this helps maybe set the working directory in Default JUnit run configuration as well as
and fixing all remaining run configurations.